# Reading and writing an Excel sheet with form elements using PHP on Linux

Tags: php, excel

One of our clients is trying to find a way to automate filling out a form that is supplied by one of their vendors.  It is an Excel spreadsheet that contains dropdowns and checkboxes.  Catch is that they must submit the form on a daily/weekly basis using this exact spreadsheet "form" and they are trying to remove the human processing from the loop.

I have tried using PHPExcel to read the files, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to set the value of the dropdowns -or- to check one of the checkboxes.

As a secondary note, if I were simply to load and then rewrite the file as a new file, the dropdowns and checkboxes simply disappear from the file.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: My understanding is that Excel form elements are generated or handled by VBScript and are rather difficult to access via PHP. Maybe a VB macro on a Windows machine is an option?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the form doesn't change, you could always bind the values to a separate data source, then change that.

Answer (score 1):

PHPExcel does not handle form element... I'm not aware of any PHP Excel library that does. You may be able to do this using COM with Excel (if you're on a Windows server), and I have been told that this might be possible under Linux using Wine or CORBA with Open/LibreOffice. Using ODBC to access the Excel workbook may be another option.

Alternatively, if you're on Linux, you might be able to use Ilia Alshanetsky's [PHP Excel extension](http://ilia.ws/archives/222-PHP-Excel-Extension.html), which is a wrapper for the commercial [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) library